# SQLite from C# - Which is easier to LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework?

Tags: sqlite

What would people recommend using as a persistence approach for **Sqlite** from a C# windows forms application - LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework?

(I ask this on the basis that I've had some people say stay away from DataTables and move to one of the new approaches)

Comment: it's not that DataSets are bad. You can actually use LINQ with DataTables; but DataSets carry a larger overhead than entities that's why I use them a lot. Plus, I'm addicted to LINQ.

Comment: Hi Martin - do you have a preferred driver/approach to use LINQ-to-sql with SqlLite then.  I'm come up with three possibilities so far to look at: http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/, http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/ ,  http://codefornothing.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/sqlite-data-provider-for-subsonic-part-2/

Answer (score 4):

LINQ-to-SQL is only available for SQL Server.  That may limit your choices somewhat.

Apparently there's a project called DbLinq that tries to port the LINQ-to-SQL interfaces to other databases: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/ . Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I saw the following suggested on another link http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/ also...  I'm not sure however how solid either of these two are, any ideas?

Comment: Wish I knew. The fact they exist shows just how much resistance there is to EF though! My next project will be Fluent NHibernate (http://fluentnhibernate.org/)

Comment: just briefly - what's the main thrust of this resistance to EF (being somewhat new to .NET)

Comment: EF is a heavyweight ORM. It establishes a conceptual model between your database and code mappings, so your structure looks like DB=>DB mapping XML=>Conceptual XML=>Object mapping XML=>POCO's. Complex! L2S is a more quick & dirty way to query SQL Server only, where tables are basically mapped to objects directly. People love it. Perf has historically been better with L2S, but that will change if it hasn't already. Mostly MS bungled the rollout. Read the comments here for more reactions: http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx